# Using Single element of Array as service constructor argument in symfony2

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, dependency-injection, parameter-passing

In the symfony2 docs at http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html it states that parameters (in service definitions) can be defined as arrays e.g:

```
parameters:
    foo.class:"Foo"
    foo.args:
        - arg1
        - arg2
```

I want to know how to pass a single element of the foo.args array to the service constructor i.e:

```
services:
    foo:
        class:"%foo.class%"
        arguments:["%foo.args.1%"] //this line is in question.does this resolve to
                                   //"arg1"?if not, what does?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation won't work.

Internally symfony would try to access `array['1']` (key=string) instead of `array[1]` (key=int).

Consider using a **[service factory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html#passing-arguments-to-the-factory-method)** that in turn creates the service with the desired element of the array as argument ...

... or just filter the array elements in the constructor of the class.

Comment: Thanks.just one more thing: so if the keys were strings and the array was nested(had more than one dimension), it would work?just asking that because i'm wondering how it processes the "dots" in the parameter name, to resolve whether it's part of the paramter name or the key.